# Увеличивать число с каждым кликом на 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Реализовал увеличение на единичку при каждом клике, но не понимаю как сделать, чтобы увеличивал на 10 или 20 за клик, прошу помочь

```
var number = 20;
$('#items-more').click(function(evt){ 
  number++;

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?= $fullLink; ?>",
    success: function(data){
      alert(+number);
    } 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: так `number+=10;` не работает?

Comment: `alert(+number);` зачем тут плюс? он ничего не делает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто прибавлять 10 к переменной.

```
var number = 20;
$('#items-more').click(function(evt){ 
  number+=10;

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?= $fullLink; ?>",
    success: function(data){
      alert(number);
    } 
  }); 
});
```